# CiviEvent: Scheduled Reminders going out late

Tags: civievent, scheduled-reminders

Drupal 7.69 and Civi 5.23.0

We've noticed that some of our Scheduled email reminders for events set up through CiviEvent are going out late. I've looked into email logs and it looks like scheduled reminders for events are sent out once per day at 9:16am.

This causes issues for e.g. events that begin at 5pm where we want to send a scheduled reminder 2 hours before the event to remind participants -- emails like this have ended up being delivered at 9:16am the following day.

Is there any way to fix this?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the run frequency of the scheduled job called **Send Scheduled Reminders** at Administer > System Settings > Scheduled Jobs.

It may just be set to *Daily*. Change it to *Every time cron job runs*. Then make sure your run frequency of your cron job is set to something more often, like 15 min.

Comment: Thanks Andy. We just started using Events in CiviCRM and had exactly the same issue.  The day before reminders were perfect but ones for 2 hours or 15 mins before the event did not fire.  Our cron runs every 5 mins and changing it to 'Every time cron runs' has addresed the issue.  I think the default for this job needs to change as it would never work for reminders that had intraday resolution.  A really simple gotcha :-)